# Owl Carousel 2 Not Working Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm having a problem with a JQuery Carousel loading within Magento - the code worked perfectly before copying in Magento.

Head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
items:1,
dots:true,
dotsSpeed:true,
responsiveClass:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
        nav:true,
        dots:false
    },
    768:{
        nav:true,
        dots:false
    },
    970:{
        nav:false
    },
    1170:{
        nav:false
    }
}
})  
});
</script>
```

Page.xml calls the files successfully

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/owl.carousel.js</name></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/owl.carousel.css</stylesheet></action>
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the Web Ontology Language, [tag:owl].  I've removed the tag.  Please be sure to read the tag descriptions, it helps get the right eyes on your question.  Tagging with a language (e.g., [tag:javascript]) often helps, too.

Comment: Apologies @JoshuaTaylor wasn't aware there was a language called Owl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are adding your noConflict looks incorrect. Try replacing the $'s with the word jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
```

Comment: Any time :) Good luck with Magento.